# How to provide other members’ information to users through Facebook Graph API

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I’m making a dating application that provides ‘members’ information (Facebook profile) to a user’ just like other dating applications. And I used Facebook Graph API below but I would like someone to tell me about ‘how to provide other members’ information to a user’.

1. Firstly, I registered my application in Facebook developers
2. I was approved with functions I need to use through 'Submit Items for Approval' (my Approved Items: email, public_profile, User_photo, User_like, user_work_history, user_education_history)
3. Then, I created member DB through a server and as a result, I can check all users’ ID with interlocked Facebook login.
4. So if a user logs in with her/his account in my application, (s)he can call her/his detail information in the account. (User_photo, User_like, user_work_history, user_education_history)
5. But the problem is, the user needs to receive members’ information around him/her (User_photo) but it doesn’t seem to work. (public_profile information can be provided)
6. It means, after receiving the user’s ID, it is forwarded to a server to use {user-id}/albums and {user-id}/photos call source. But it still says there is no result for both. (Brings GraphUser information through Facebook login and brings user_id through GraphUser.getId() )

So I am wondering if only the information in the ID section of logged in account is visible, but it seems an application called highli*** is using the service.

I would like to request someone to help me to solve the problem of # 5,6? Please help me (Please see the source)

Bring album_id through the method below by using user_id information

```
           new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "/user_id/albums", null, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {

       @Override
       public void onCompleted(Response response) {
       }                                }).executeAsync();
```

Bring photo information through the method below by using album_id information

```
           new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "/album_id/photos", null, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {

       @Override
       public void onCompleted(Response response) {

       }                                }).executeAsync();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Facebook Graph API is returning no results (an empty array) then more than likely it is a permissions issue.

In order for you to access another user’s information, the other user must also have given the required permissions.

**For example:**
User A is requesting the information of User B. Both users must grant the permissions below for the following requests:

```
user_friends, user_photos 

{UserB-Id}/albums 
{UserB-Id}/photos
{Album-Id}/photos
```

I suggest using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) to test your requests. Here you can mock a token for your app and also apply different permissions, even before Facebook gives you approval to use them.

You can find more info on permissions [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3).

Comment: Very Thank you for giving the answer I looking for!
However, it was a comment if there is a part that can not go a little understanding.
Although it means that your mean there must be accepted between the both..
You're also comes to accept the source that was used in "A when it is in a position of B?

Comment: I even while logout B, but eager to if it is automatically processed on the system.
Can you give a little more of the tips of both between the consent?